# Count the total number of times a value has been selected

Tags: php, wordpress

A custom post type has the following drop down menu options to list homes for sale as viewable, being built, sold, or proposed build. Is it possible to count the total number of homes in each of the categories and publish it on the site? For example "there are X houses being built". Where X is the total homes with the status being built.

```
<select name="listing_status_dropdown"><?php
        $status_options = array('Viewable', 'Being Built', 'Sold', 'Proposed Build');
        foreach ($status_options as $the_status) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $the_status; ?>" <?php echo selected( $the_status, $listing_status_dropdown ); ?>>
          <?php echo $the_status; } ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Is `$the_status` a meta field?

Comment: $listing_status_dropdown = esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'listing_status_dropdown', true ) );

Comment: if ( ! isset( $_POST['listing_status_dropdown'] ) ) {return; }
$my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['listing_status_dropdown'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'listing_status_dropdown', $my_data );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do custom queries for each of these meta values, and then count the number of posts that are returned using the [`$found_posts` property of WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties). For example:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'listing_status_dropdown',
    'meta_value' => 'Viewable'
);
$viewable = new WP_Query( $args );

// Display the number of 'Viewable' entries
echo $viewable->found_posts;
```

Comment: THANKS! I just needed to add a line to the array. 'post_type' => 'listings',